# Drag-and-drop arrangement of a MultiButton list

Tags: codenameone

What is the best way to implement a list of MultiButtons that you can arrange by dragging and dropping?

At the moment I'm adding MultiButtons to a container and I'm implementing drag & drop for each of those multibuttons. When I drop it I'm doing this:

```
@Override
public void drop(Component dragged, int x, int y) {
    Container container = getParent();

    dragged.getParent().removeComponent(dragged);
    container.addComponent(container.getComponentIndex(this), dragged);
}
```

It doesn't always work, but I can't help thing this functionality may already be present in the `MultiList` or that there's probably a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default container automatically rearranges components in drag and drop so you don't really need to do anything other than setting the component as draggable and the container as drop target.

Comment: Brilliant. How hard would it be do have a list I can side-swipe to delete as well as drag-and-drop reordering?

Comment: Thanks, this is probably easily doable although not built in. You can use a drag listener to follow the direction of the drag and consume it in case of a side drag. You can also provide a hint e.g. delete/archive during the drag.

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation for the "hint during drag"? Can't find it!!

Comment: There is no API for that other than the drag events, you can use them to modify the component state to indicate what you are trying to accomplish.